# I am a bisexual muslima

Tags: halal-haram

The thing is that I worship Allah, I always pray to him, as he is our god and creator

I am bisexual  , I tried hiding it for a really long time but I fell for a female, I know that having intercourse with the same gender is a sin.
But what if I don't? What if I only love my partner, with out any sexual interactions?

I know that my love is purely romantic, nothing sexual, and I fear my god greatly to even think about intercourse with the same gender.

I read and searched about it and everything says that gay love is haram because of the intercourse, I know that, I respect that, I'll go by that, and I'll never have intercourse with the same gender, I'll only love, and pure love is far different from sexual love.

I won't have any intercourse with the same gender, but I can't hide me love, I tried and believe me I tried for years and years but I can't not love both genders.

I can't choose who to fall in love for, but I can choose who I'll have intercourse with.

Allah will and is always in my heart. I fear Allah. I love Allah, I pray to Allah.

Can't my love be pure? Only pure? I'll never and I swear to Allah have intercourse with the same gender, ever.

Comment: As written, this post is simply attracting vague speculative advice rather than any sort of practical *answers* (see also relevant meta discussion: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/868/22); I would suggest you take the time to better focus your question to fit the Stack Exchange model (see also help centre pages "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)")

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand that why you've called yourself bisexual while you are not going to have any sexual intercourse with the *same gender*. Do you kiss her with lust? If you do, then you don't love her. I swear you don't. You may love her *face beauty*, *body fit*, anything else, but not her identity. Listen, girl, prophet Mohammed loves his companions, his wives and so on. Psychologically, you can describe why does he love them. We are in 2016, btw. So, don't beat around the bush. In addition, Mohammed(pbuh) says, "*if someone loves his brother, he has to tell him that he loves him*." Love is not prohibited, but sometimes is not love what we mean but lust, which is utterly different. Anyway, I love you my sister on Islam that why I am here to release your confusion and let you feel better by advising you. In conclusion, Mohammed (pbuh) says, " *By who my soul(lifetime) is with his knowledge, you do not go to heaven until you believe and you do not believe until you love, is not better to guide you on something that if you do it you love each other? spread the salutation among you* " Aslamu Alikum. I won't tell you that "*GIRL, YOU HAVE TO GET MARRIED RIGHT NOW*" as an advice, because I believe you that you are smart and you know what you are talking about by saying "*I can't choose who to fall in love for, but I can choose who I'll have intercourse with.*" I hope you will find the groom who loves you and you do as well. Keep your love with her pure. Peace.

Comment: Brother Saif, I don't understand why you've considered my answer is rude, but I believe that everyone has its own perspective. I would like to know why it is partly rude. I know my style is not as other but not wrong. We have to be honest with ourselves and our mind that God gives it to us. Kindly, explain to me why what I've said is kind of rude.